# How to select a binary datatype column and show as human readable format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, sqldatatypes

In MySQL, one of my table is having binary data type set. I want to select this column data and show it as string (human readable format).I am able to see this works in Oracle , but the same fails in MySQL.

```
MySQL : select CAST(tablename.columnname as VARCHAR) from tablename;  **Fails**
Oracle: select bin2char(tablename.columnname) from tablename; **Success**
```

CONVERT function also fails. Please let me know any other options is available.

Below is my MySQL server version.
**MySQL version - 5.6.20-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log**

Basically I want to decode the binary data.

Comment: `bin2char` is **not** an Oracle-supplied function. Maybe it's user-defined function? In which case you could look at its source.

Comment: The only reference I can find for a `BIN2CHAR` function is for DB2, appearing in [this article](https://www.mcpressonline.com/analytics-cognitive/db2/techtip-cast-binary-data-to-built-in-data-types)

Comment: In Oracle there's `DUMP()` and `RAWTOHEX()`.

Comment: @APC , yes it looks like , this is not provided by Oracle and written by developer

Answer (score 1):

One option is [HEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_hex):

> For a string argument `str`, `HEX()` returns a hexadecimal string representation of `str` where each byte of each character in `str` is converted to two hexadecimal digits. (Multibyte characters therefore become more than two digits.) The inverse of this operation is performed by the `UNHEX()` function.